# How to display posts month by month?

Tags: wp-query

How could wp-query be used to show posts month by month, and have it only show the past year? Or is it possible some wp_archive hack could handle this?

Comment: See also my answer here, it's an handy function I made: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/276929/10381

Answer (score 3):

WordPress 3.7 introduced the [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) to display posts month by month:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'month' => $month
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Note** : $month refers to month number (1-12)

Comment: Perfect Solution!!!!.. Thanks for saving my time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not a hack it's a function. You can simply use `wp_get_archives`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

Alternatively you can use a `wp_query` with a time format for actual content, for instance,

```
//December
$query = new WP_Query( 'monthnum=12' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I should clarify that the code is based on a snippet that I saw.

```
    <?php

$blogtime = date('Y');
$prev_limit_year = $blogtime - 1;
$prev_month = '';
$prev_year = '';

$args = array(
         'posts_per_page' => 20,
         'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

$postsbymonth = new WP_Query($args);

while($postsbymonth->have_posts()) {

    $postsbymonth->the_post();

    if(get_the_time('F') != $prev_month || get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year && get_the_time('Y') == $prev_limit_year) {

                   echo "<h2>".get_the_time('F, Y')."</h2>\n\n";

        }

    ?>

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                <?php // your other template tags ?>


    <?php

    $prev_month = get_the_time('F');
    $prev_year = get_the_time('Y');

}

        ?>
```

Comment: Can you get this to print out the months with zero posts as well?