# How to get posts from a current post's month?

Tags: posts, query-posts, get-posts

I want to display the titles of the post of the same month as the blog post.
I tried this ..

```
<?php $year = the_date('Y')?>
<?php $month = the_date('M')?>

      <?php  $theids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND MONTH(post_date)= '".$month."' AND YEAR(post_date) = '".$year."' ORDER BY post_date ASC");
       foreach ($theids as $theid): ?>
        <?php echo $theid->post_title; ?>

       <?php endforeach; ?>
```

but it's returning nothing. How can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: What does your sql query look like? When testing sql, you should place your query string in a variable, then echo/dump/log the variable to see what sql is being called. With that said, try a lower case `m` when getting the month, like `the_date('m')`. Upper case M returns the textual three letters like Jan - Dec

Comment: tried the_date('m'), still not working

Comment: If you echo the query, what do you get?

Comment: See also my answer here, it's an handy function I made:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/276929/10381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`date_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters) which can handle this and an SQL query is not a good practice when you can take advantage of WordPress Query API:

```
$pid = 1; // post ID here

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => get_the_date('Y', $pid),
            'month' => get_the_date('m', $pid)
        ),
    ),
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

print_r( $posts );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it necessary to define post id?

Comment: @Omer not really, but you can replace the date functions with static dates: `get_the_date('Y', $pid)` as `2017` and `get_the_date('m', $pid)` as `04`

Comment: can we also get post of the day or week like you are getting from `year` and `month`?