# Query not work for current taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query, errors, timestamp

Hi i want to show current taxonomy post type count by month but it show total post count istead of current tax. please help me. i am trying to solve this problem almost 3 weeks.

```
 <?php 
$post_type = "myposttype";
$timestamp_start = strtotime("first day of next month -1 year midnight");
$start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp_start);

$posts = get_posts([
    "nopaging" => TRUE,
    "post_type" => $post_type,
    "date_query" => [
        "after" => $start,
    ],
]);



// sort by month

$tab = [];

foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $month = mysql2date("F", $post->post_date);

    if (!isset($tab[$month])) {
        $tab[$month] = 0;
    }

    $tab[$month]++;

}


// display

$timestamp = $timestamp_start;
$now = time();

while ($timestamp < $now) {

    $month = date_i18n("F", $timestamp);

    $count = $tab[$month] ?? 0; // need PHP 7

    echo '<li>'."$month: $count". '</li>';


    // next month

    $timestamp = strtotime("+1 month", $timestamp);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query is for ALL posts in that post type as you are overwriting `$posts` when using `$posts = get_posts()`.
You need to pass the Taxonomy parameter correctly as explained [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You need to modify your code along those lines. So maybe change `$posts = get_queried_object()->term_id;` to `$termID = get_queried_object()->term_id;` and use that in your `tax_query`

Comment: thanks for your attention but problem is that i have about 20 taxonomy and 30 term in every taxonomy. thats why i want to get post count by month with get_queried

Comment: It doesn't matter how many posts, taxonomies or terms you have, if you structure your query properly, you will get what you want. While testing, you can use: `$thePosts = query_posts($args);` and `$thePosts ->found_posts;` to get your results count.

Comment: Also, I think that this will help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176141/display-posts-by-month